# Multiple instances of Vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have to following situation with vue2/vuex; Let's say I have a users module where I store all users I fetched from my api.

I use this module to populate, for example, dropdown lists containing all users.

Now I also have a users page, but this page has the option to filter, paginate  users etc. This happens serverside, so the module will be updated with the new list of (filtered) users.

Should I create two separate modules for both usecases (usersOptions and usersView)? To me it would seem more logical to create two instances of the user store, but apparently that's not possible with Vuex. How would you handle a situation like this?

Here is an example of the my users module:

```
import UserRepository from '@/repositories/UserRepository';

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    loading: false,
    users: [],
  },
  getters: {
    isLoading(state) {
      return state.loading;
    },
    data(state) {
      return state.users;
    },
    options: (state) => (value = 'id', label = 'name') => state.users.map(
      (user) => ({ value: user[value], label: user[label] }),
    ),
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_LOADING(state, payload) {
      state.loading = payload;
    },
    SET_DATA(state, payload) {
      state.users = payload;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    fetch({ commit }) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        commit('SET_LOADING', true);
        UserRepository.index({ limit: 0 })
          .then((response) => {
            const users = response.data.data;
            commit('SET_DATA', users);
            resolve(response);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
          })
          .finally(() => {
            commit('SET_LOADING', false);
          });
      });
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Hard to say without actually knowing [your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It really depends on how you save your data in the store. Can you share that with us?

Comment: I've updated my post with an example of my users module.

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell us the different urls you can use to request the full or filtered/paginated data?

Comment: For the options I would use `/api/users/search?limit=0` and for populating the view I would use `/api/users/search?limit15&page=1` and with a JSON payload for the filters or sorting (`[{field: "name", direction: "desc"}])`

Comment: Okay, I added this as an answer. I didn't add support for filters/sorting but I guess, you'll get an idea of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuitively, I'd do something like that. Haven't tested it but it's probably not ready to use yet.

```
import UserRepository from '@/repositories/UserRepository';

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    loading: false,
    users: [],
  },
  getters: {
    isLoading(state) {
      return state.loading;
    },
    data(state) {
      return state.users;
    },
    usersView() {
      return state.users.view;
    },
    usersOptions() {
      return state.users.options;
    },
    options: (state) => (value = 'id', label = 'name') => state.users.map(
      (user) => ({ value: user[value], label: user[label] }),
    ),
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_LOADING(state, payload) {
      state.loading = payload;
    },
    SET_DATA(state, key, payload) {
      state.users[key] = payload;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    fetch({ commit }, params) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        commit('SET_LOADING', true);
        UserRepository.index(params)
          .then((response) => {
            resolve(response.data.data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
          })
          .finally(() => {
            commit('SET_LOADING', false);
          });
      });
    },
    fetchOptions() {
        this.dispatch('fetch', { limit: 0 }).then((users) {            
            commit('SET_DATA', 'options', users);
        })
    },
    fetchView() {
        this.dispatch('fetch', { limit: 15, page: 1 }).then((users) {            
            commit('SET_DATA', 'view', users);
        })
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks this seems like a pretty solid solution.

Answer (score 0):

Two stores its never the soultion in my opinion,
try to seperate to 2 modules.
find more here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I just realise I've been using the term 'store' where I should use the term 'module'. I've updated my original post.